# Unable to authenticate Looker API in Databricks using Python

Tags: python-3.x, databricks, looker

I want to access some charts -which I have saved in Looker- within Databricks. Part of this process is the authentication. I have one Looker auth-script which works but only pulls the tabular results into Databricks which corresponds to a Looker-View. Instead, I want ONLY the charts to be accessed in Databricks which will correspond to a Looker-look or Looker-space. However, when I follow the tutorial on https://discourse.looker.com/t/generating-a-powerpoint-presentation-from-all-looks-in-a-space/8191, I am not able to authenticate with their script. Hopefully, someone can help.

```
**Working auth-script for Looker-Views**
import looker_tools as tools

api=tools.LookerApi(
  api_endpoint="abcd", 
  client_id=dbutils.secrets.get(scope="looker-api", key="looker_client_id"), 
  client_secret=dbutils.secrets.get(scope="looker-api",key="looker_client_secret")
)
token = api.login()



**Desired auth-script for Looker-Space/Looks as per tutorial link**

looker_instance = 'your-company.looker.com'
target_space = # 'Period over Period' Space on the Looker instance

client_id = 'xxxxxxxx'
client_secret = 'xxxxxxxx'

# instantiate Auth API
unauthenticated_client = looker_client.ApiClient(configuration=None)
unauthenticated_client.configuration.host = f'https://{looker_instance}:19999/api/3.0/'
unauthenticated_authApi = looker_client.ApiAuthApi(unauthenticated_client)

# authenticate client
token = unauthenticated_authApi.login(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
client = looker_client.ApiClient(header_name='Authorization', header_value='token ' + token.access_token)
client.configuration.host = f'https://{looker_instance}:19999/api/3.0/'
```

**I tried translating the code from Current to DESIRED auth-script but the error states the looker_client is not defined!**

```
looker_instance = 'abcd'
target_space = 123

client_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="looker-api", key="looker_client_id")
client_secret = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="looker-api",key="looker_client_secret")

# instantiate Auth API
unauthenticated_client = looker_client.ApiClient(configuration=None) --> This line fails!!
unauthenticated_client.configuration.host = f'https://{looker_instance}:19999/api/3.0/'
unauthenticated_authApi = looker_client.ApiAuthApi(unauthenticated_client)

# authenticate client
token = unauthenticated_authApi.login(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
client = looker_client.ApiClient(header_name='Authorization', header_value='token ' + token.access_token)
client.configuration.host = f'https://{looker_instance}:19999/api/3.0/'
```

I hope someone can help on how to define looker_client properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this one was resolved here: https://discourse.looker.com/t/generating-a-powerpoint-presentation-from-all-looks-in-a-space/8191/15?u=izzy for those following along at home. There's another issue, but the `NameError: name ‘looker_client’ is not defined` error was resolved by adding a necessary import:

```
import looker_client_30 as looker_client
```